# How should I align the tenses: I {would / would have} be sleeping right now if I {knew / had known} that the class {will / is going to} get cancelled

Tags: tense, modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

Which statement is correct grammatically?

> I **would** be sleeping right now if I **had known** that the class **will** get cancelled. (due to rain)
>
> I **would have** been sleeping right now if I **knew** the class **is going to** get cancelled. (due to heavy **rain/rains**)

I've highlighted several parts and I would appreciate if someone could point out the mistake in each of them.

Comment: Has the class been cancelled at the time you say this, or are you merely confident that it will be cancelled at some time after you say this?

Comment: @StoneyB The context is like this... 1. There was no notification that class is cancelled. 2. Students who've unfortunately come are expressing dissatisfaction amongst themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, class was cancelled at some time before you say this, but after you got up.

For instance, you got up at 7 am for an 8 am class, and discovered when you arrived that the class had been cancelled. You say this at 8:15.

If that is the case, you want

- a Present Irrealis ('unreal') form for your imaginary present state of sleeping, with the past-form modal *would* expressing present-tense irreality
- a Past Irrealis for your imaginary past knowledge, with the 'sham' past perfect or double past, one past form expressing irreality and the other expressing past tense)
- a Past Realis for the real fact, with the past-form modal *would* expressing that the cancellation lay in the future when you got up in the past

> I **would be sleeping**<sub>Pres Irr</sub> right now if I **had known**<sub>Past Irr</sub> [when I got up] that the class { **would / was going to**}<sub>Past Rea Fut</sub> get cancelled.

Comment: That's all fine and good, but is the OP just supposed to take your word for it?

Comment: @User1 It's a chronic problem here, and on ELU, and in English pedagogy generally, that there is no Standard Grammatical Authority to which questioners can be readily referred, or even a Standard Grammatical Terminology, because English grammar has been continually transforming for 50 years. The references I consult when I'm in doubt (H&P, Aarts, McCawley) are not accessible online, and the EFL sites I've seen show no evidence of knowing more about English grammar than I do. So, yeah: I can spend my time here looking up spurious footnotes, or I can spend it giving sound answers.

Comment: @StoneyB Is it OK to say "I would have been sleeping right now if I had known that the class was going to get cancelled"? I think it works. :)

Comment: @KinzleB Not really, though it's not impossible that a) there could be some odd circumstances where *would have been* in the main clause would reflect a futurive inference in the past, or b) a native speaker might inadvertently produce it out of the tangle of time references.